# Change an image during animation using storyboard

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, storyboard

I was looking for a way to change an *Image* during a storyboard, or more specifically, change the `Source` property of the image to point to a new image resource. There seems to be a `StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames` and a `DiscreteStringKeyFrame` but this does not work (as far as I can tell) since the Source property of the Image is of type `ImageSource`

My current storyboard looks like this

```
<Storyboard x:Key="TransitionImage">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
        BeginTime="00:00:00" 
        Storyboard.TargetName="image" 
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.7000000" Value="0.2"/>
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.5000000" Value="1"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames
        BeginTime="00:00:00"
        Storyboard.TargetName="image"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.Source)">
        <!-- This does not work -->
        <DiscreteStringKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.7000000" Value="check_24.png"/>
    </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
        BeginTime="00:00:00" 
        Storyboard.TargetName="image"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.7000000" Value="0.2"/>
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.5000000" Value="1"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

and the image

```
<Image x:Name="image" 
       Source="delete_24.png"
       Width="32" Height="32"
       Margin="8"
       RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform/>
            <SkewTransform/>
            <RotateTransform/>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

Can I change the `Source` of the image as part of the storyboard or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Okay, solved it myself. Seems you have to use the `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` and `DiscreteObjectKeyFrame` as shown below:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
    BeginTime="00:00:00" 
    Storyboard.TargetName="image"
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.Source)">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.7000000">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            <BitmapImage UriSource="check_24.png" />
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Comment: How do you bind the BitmapImage UriSource with dynamic content