# Animate a sprite by using two images

Tags: c#, wpf

I would have thought this was a common desire, but I'll be damned if I can find this.

I simply want to Animate an image by swapping two images back and forth. I tried StoryBoard, but apparently you can't change the source in a storyboard.  The only answer I can come up with is a Timer, which I don't think is the best way.

**Edit:** [How do I animate image content in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783619/how-do-i-animate-image-content-in-wpf) Came up in the "Similiar Questions" window.  And while this will do what I want, it is "hackish" as the OP of it says, and it only swaps two images, what if I wanted a whole sequence of 10 or 20 or 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another post here on SO whose answer sounds like it could solve your problem: [Change an image during animation using storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799565/change-a-wpf-image-during-a-stroryboard)

The problem with this approach is that it also doesn't satify your request for supporting an arbitrary number of images.

I was going to propose a different method that involves databinding the `Image` `Source` to the image path, and then in code behind simply changing the path, but I haven't gotten it to work yet.

Here's an article that seems to have an elegant way to handle your requirements: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/364529/Animation-using-Storyboards-in-WPF

Hopefully that will work for you.

Comment: The article at the bottom looks good, I will need to try it and see if I can get it to work.